# Cartesian projection issue in a FITS image through PyFITS / AstroPy

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap, fits, pyfits, astropy

I've looked and looked for a solution to this problem and am turning up nothing.

I'm generating rectangular FITS images through matplotlib and subsequently applying WCS coordinates to them using AstroPy (or PyFITS).  My images are in galactic latitude and longitude, so the header keywords appropriate for my maps should be `GLON-CAR` and `GLAT-CAR` (for Cartesian projection).  I've looked at [other maps](http://darkclouds.u-gakugei.ac.jp/) that use this same map projection in [SAO DS9](http://ds9.si.edu/site/Home.html) and the coordinates work great... the grid is perfectly orthogonal as it should be.  The FITS standard projections can be found [here.](http://herschel.esac.esa.int/hcss-doc-8.0/load/um/html/Sadm.Ch.Wcs.html)

But when I generate my maps, the coordinates are not at all Cartesian.  Here's a side-by-side comparison of my map (left) and another reference map of roughly the same region (right).  Both are listed `GLON-CAR` and `GLAT-CAR` in the FITS header, but mine is screwy when looked at in SAO DS9 (note that the coordinate grid is something SAO DS9 generates based on the data in the FITS header, or at least stored somewhere in the FITS file):

[image: (left) my map, and (right) reference map. HEADER keywords are the same, both Cartesian]

This is problematic, because the coordinate-assigning algorithm will assign incorrect coordinates to each pixel if the projection is wrong.

Has anyone encountered this, or know what could be the problem?

I've tried applying other projections (just to see how they perform in SAO DS9) and they come out fine... but my Cartesian and Mercator projections do not come out with the orthogonal grid like they should.

I can't believe this would be a bug in AstroPy, but I can't find any other cause... unless my arguments in the header are incorrectly formatted, but I still don't see how that could cause the problem I'm experiencing.  Or would you recommend using something else?  (I've looked at matplotlib basemap but have had some trouble getting that to work on my computer).

My header code is below:

```
 from __future__ import division
 import numpy as np
 from astropy.io import fits as pyfits # or use 'import pyfits, same thing'

 #(lots of code in between: defining variables and simple calculations...
 #probably not relevant)

 header['BSCALE'] = (1.00000, 'REAL = TAPE*BSCALE + BZERO')
 header['BZERO'] = (0.0)
 header['BUNIT'] = ('mag ', 'UNIT OF INTENSITY')
 header['BLANK'] = (-100.00, 'BLANK VALUE')
 header['CRVAL1'] = (glon_center, 'REF VALUE POINT DEGR')   #FIRST COORDINATE OF THE CENTER
 header['CRPIX1'] = (center_x+0.5, 'REF POINT PIXEL LOCATION') ## REFERENCE X PIXEL
 header['CTYPE1'] = ('GLON-CAR', 'COORD TYPE : VALUE IS DEGR')
 header['CDELT1'] = (-glon_length/x_length, 'COORD VALUE INCREMENT WITH COUNT DGR')   ### degrees per pixel
 header['CROTA1'] = (0, 'CCW ROTATION in DGR')            
 header['CRVAL2'] = (glat_center, 'REF VALUE POINT DEGR') #Y COORDINATE OF THE CENTER
 header['CRPIX2'] = (center_y+0.5, 'REF POINT PIXEL LOCATION') #Y REFERENCE PIXEL 
 header['CTYPE2'] = ('GLAT-CAR', 'COORD TYPE: VALUE IS DEGR')   # WAS CAR OR TAN
 header['CDELT2'] = (glat_length/y_length, 'COORD VALUE INCREMENT WITH COUNT DGR') #degrees per pixel  
 header['CROTA2'] = (rotation, 'CCW ROTATION IN DEGR')                               #NEGATIVE ROTATES CCW around origin (bottom left). 
 header['DATAMIN'] = (data_min, 'Minimum data value in the file') 
 header['DATAMAX'] = (data_max, 'Maximum data value in the file')
 header['TELESCOP'] = ("Produced from 2MASS")

 pyfits.update(filename, map_data, header)
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the modern definition of the `-CAR` projection (from Calabretta et al.), `GLON-CAR`/`GLAT-CAR` projection only produces a rectilinear grid if `CRVAL2` is set to zero. If `CRVAL2` is not zero, then the grid is curved (this should have nothing to do with Astropy). You can try and fix this by adjusting `CRVAL2` and `CRPIX2` so that `CRVAL2` is zero. Does this help?

Just to clarify what I mean, try, after your code above, and before writing out the file:

```
header['CRPIX2'] -= header['CRVAL2'] / header['CDELT2']
header['CRVAL2'] = 0.
```

Any luck?

If you look at the header for the 'reference' file you looked at, you'll see that `CRVAL2` is zero there. Just to be clear, there's nothing *wrong* with `CRVAL2` being non-zero, but the grid is then no longer rectilinear.

Comment: That's it!!!  Wow, thanks so much... never would have spotted that solution on my own.

Just a note for anyone stumbling on this in the future... since this means setting the reference coordinate as the origin (0,0), the last piece of the puzzle is to determine the pixel values (CRPIX1 and CRPIX2) for the origin.  So depending on the map's coordinates, one or both of your reference pixels may be negative values.  I had to modify astrofrog's code slightly to make it work for me (particularly, I had to multiply by the inverse - that is, 1/header['CDELT1'] - to get the right values.

Comment: @Teachey - ah yes, I got it round the wrong way - fixing!